# Should I use Liouville thm or continuity?

Tags: complex-analysis

Make an examples $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ holomorph (If it exists) with the properties:(Justify your answer)

$|f(z)|\leq \frac{1}{100}$ if $|z|\leq 1$ and

$|f(z)-1|\leq \frac{1}{100}$ if $|z-3|\leq 1$.

**My attemp:** I confuesd to   use Liouville thm or continuity?
Please guide me how should I think about it!

Comment: If $g$ is an entire function, it is continuous in particular, and hence, bounded by some constant $a = a(D) > 0$ on the disc $D.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define $g(z)=0$ on $|z|\le 1$ and $g(z)=1$ on $|z-3|\le 1$. Then $g$ is analytic on a neigoborhood of $K=\{|z|\le 1\}\cup \{|z-3|\le 1\}$. Note that $\Bbb C\setminus K$ is connected. By Runge's theorem, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a polynomial $p(z)$ such that
$$
|g(z)-p(z)|\le\epsilon,\quad\forall z\in K.
$$ If we let $\epsilon =\frac{1}{100}$, then $p$ is a function we are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You want an entire function satisfying the given two properties.

What about the constant function $f(z)=1/200$ ?

Comment: $|1/200 - 1| = 199/200 > 1/100$.